# Concurrency in java

Tags: java, concurrency

```
public class MyTest {
      ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();
      public void initialize() {
       //....
      }
      private void editArray(int num) {
           // modified the array
      }
      public void func(int n) {
             for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                  editArray(i);
             }
      }
}
```

I hope to execute "editArray" function in the forloop concurrently, which means n threads(call editArray function) can execute concurrently, how can I do that and add a lock for ArrayList array ? I google a lot, most of tutorials just teach how to spawn thread for different objects. What I want is that spawn thread in a single object.

I mainly want to know how to call a function concurrently in java.
Thanks.

Comment: what is insert(i) inside the for loop?

Comment: insertMap function. I spell it by mistake.Thanks

Comment: synchronizing the `insertMap` function could suffice. But `ArrayList` is not designed to handle concurrency. You may want to look rather at a Queue, for example a ConcurrentBlockingQueue.

Comment: What is the point in passing an `int` to `insertMap()` without also passing the list? What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: I mainly want to know how to call a function concurrently in java, most tutorial spawn threads by creating more than one object, this is not what I want. Thanks.

Comment: If insertMap method is just inserting into Map then why to create multiple threads to insert. What you are doing in for loop is good. Why extra overhead of thread creation and management?

Comment: I mainly want to know how to call a function concurrently in java, most tutorial spawn threads by creating more than one object, this is not what I want. Thanks

Comment: I edit my original question. Hope you can understand my question.

Comment: @cacao Each thread itself is an object and so you cannot avoid spawning multiple thread objects if the intent is to run concurrently. But then I am not sure if this is the one you are looking for. Instead of separate class declaration for thread, have an anonymous one like this: - In the for loop use - `final int j = i; new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { editArray(j); } }).start();`